# Problem with saving kable table (install_phantomjs)

Tags: r, save, knitr, kable

Let's consider very simple table created by `kable`

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

x <- data.frame(1:3, 2:4, 3:5)
x <- kable(x, format = "pipe", col.names = c("X_1", "X_2", "X_3"), caption = "My_table")
```

I want to save this table into .pdf format

`x %>% save_kable("My_table.pdf")`

But I get error:

```
PhantomJS not found. You can install it with webshot::install_phantomjs(). If it is installed, please make sure the phantomjs executable can be found via the PATH variable.
```

However, when trying to install it by proposed command:

`webshot::install_phantomjs()`

I get error:

```
Error in utils::download.file(url, method = method, ...) : 
  cannot open URL 'https://github.com/wch/webshot/releases/download/v0.3.1/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows.zip'
```

So my question is - Is there any possbility to save kable table without using phanomjs?

Answer (score 1):

The command works for me and the URL is also available.

I suspect that the file (it's a `.zip` file) is being blocked by your firewall or anti-virus software.